# Store connection credentials securely in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security

I'm trying to make a web chat app for a mincraft server useing [this api](https://github.com/alecgorge/jsonapi/wiki). The [demo script](https://github.com/alecgorge/jsonapi/blob/master/sdk/js/test/test1.html) for what I want to do shows the conection info, in plain text, witch will be easyly visible from any clients computer. Is there any way I can store this securely while still having the same functionality? Preferably retrieved from mySQL with php.

Answer (score 0):

setup a proxy that adds the sensitive connection details to the request.
There is no way that i am aware of to do what you are asking in javascript.

Some tutorials about JSON cross-origin proxies may help you as they are similar to your problem.

Comment: I think I get what you mean... I'll look into it, thanks for a push in the right direction. :)